# Skip every specified line before importing to pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data file that I need certain lines skipped.

```
(1 1),skip,this
skip,this,too
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
(1 2),skip,this
skip,this,too
...
```

They do repeat every after 4 data entries. I tried the ones from this post [Pandas: ignore all lines following a specific string when reading a file into a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138175/pandas-ignore-all-lines-following-a-specific-string-when-reading-a-file-into-a) but the line nothing is being skipped and it's turning the dataframe into a MultiIndex.

I tried looping by using `startswith()` and appending to a list, however, the data is being inputted into a single column.

I'm trying to obtain this output:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
```

There's multiple files each one containing over 7M rows.  I'm looking for a fast, memory efficient way to accomplish this.

Something I tried was create a list to skip row `0,1`, then again `6, 7`. Is it possible to achieve through that?

Comment: Why not just pre-parse the file and remove any line that contains "skip" in it.

Comment: What is the criteria to skip?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the data is being read from a sensor, the file that is written contains the sensor such as `(1,1), ...`, and second row is the column name. I don't care about those for the time being, I just need the data saved to a dataframe.

Comment: So you want every four entries skipping two in between?

Comment: Yep, I tried to create a formula for that but wasn't successful either. I included that explanation in my edit.

Comment: So you don't mind storing all the data in a list first?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham that won't be an issue.

Comment: Assuming you're using the `read_csv` function, you could use the `comment` param.  However, it only allows a single character, and not a list of characters.  :/

Comment: Are you just skipping every 4 rows like [0, 1, 6, 7.....] etc? You could just generate the list or rows to skip and pass this to `skiprows` as an arg to `read_csv`

Comment: @EdChum yes, those rows are unnecessary

Comment: So if you know the number of lines in the file then you could something like `a = list(range(len_of_file)) rows = sorted(a[::6] + a[1::6])` this creates a list of the pairs of rows to skip and then `pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=rows)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presuming you want to take sections of four lines coming after the two lines to skip,  just skip two lines and take a slice of four rows from a csv reader obejct:

```
from itertools import islice, chain
import pandas as pd
import csv


def parts(r):
    _, n = next(r), next(r)
    while n:
        yield islice(r, 4)
        _, n = next(r, ""), next(r, "")
            _, n = next(r, ""), next(r, "")


with open("test.txt")as f:
        r = csv.reader(f)
        print(pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(parts(r)))))
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

Or pass the chain object to `pd.DataFrame.from_records`:

```
with open("test.txt")as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    print(pd.DataFrame.from_records(chain.from_iterable(parts(r))))

    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

Or a more general approach using a function using the consume recipe to skip lines:

```
from itertools import islice, chain
from collections import deque
import pandas as pd
import csv

def consume(iterator, n):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is none, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)


def parts(r, sec_len, skip):
    consume(r,skip)
    for sli in iter(lambda: list(islice(r, sec_len)), []):
        yield sli
        consume(r, skip)


with open("test.txt")as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    print(pd.DataFrame.from_records((chain.from_iterable(parts(r, 4, 2)))))
```

The last option is to write to an StringIo object and pass that:

```
from io import StringIO
def parts(r, sec_len, skip):
    consume(r, skip)
    for sli in iter(lambda: list(islice(r, sec_len)), []):
        yield "".join(sli)
        consume(r, skip)


with open("test.txt")as f:
    so = StringIO()
    so.writelines(parts(f, 4, 2))
    so.seek(0)
    print(pd.read_csv(so, header=None))
```

Comment: Thank you for adding a general approach as well.

Comment: No prob,  consume is only going to be useful if you are skipping multiple lines but thought it was worth throwing in

Comment: Any idea why it's causing a `MemoryError` when doing it on actual file. It's 265M and about 7.8M rows. I've opened larger files (size wise) but do you think the error is due to rows and doing `from_records`. That's where the error is occuring.

Comment: If you create a DataFrame calling list on the chain `pd.DataFrame(list(chain.from_iterable(parts(r))))` do you also get a memory error?

Comment: Yes, that one as well.

Comment: How about specifying a chunk size, something like `iterator=True, chunksize=1000` and use concat? We are not storing a great deal in memory at all so not sure why it is causing a memoryerror. Do you see your memory usage spiking?

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to just pre-scrub the file before hand:

```
with open("file.csv") as rp, open("outfile.csv", 'w') as wp:
    for line in rp:
        if 'skip' not in line:
            wp.write(line)
```

Comment: I would rather not double my data, I edited my question. That would not be efficient. I didn't downvote tho.

Comment: @Leb I think you're going to have to. This is actually memory efficient solution.

Comment: @Leb the way I see it is, either you're going to have to create a separate file, or generate a separate "in-memory" file.  I don't know of any way to have `pandas` skip lines based on a specific criteria.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to just generate the list of row numbers to skip, so determine the number of rows in the file using method here: [Count how many lines are in a CSV Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108526/count-how-many-lines-are-in-a-csv-python)

then do the following:

```
In [16]:
import io
​import pandas as pd
t="""(1 1),skip,this
skip,this,too
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12
(1 2),skip,this
skip,this,too"""
# generate initial list, using 10 her but you can get the number of rows using another metho
a = list(range(10))
# generate the pairs of rows to skips in steps
rows = sorted(a[::6] + a[1::6])
# now read it in
pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), skiprows=rows, header=None)

Out[16]:
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a repeating pattern (toss two lines, keep four) I might do something like this:

```
from io import BytesIO
with open("skipper.csv", "rb") as fp:
    lines = (line for i,line in enumerate(fp) if i % 6 >= 2)
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(b''.join(lines)), header=None)
```

which gives me

```
>>> df
    0   1   2
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12
```

Comment: might as well use a list comp, passing a generator to join will still get turned into a list

Answer (score -1):

I would pipe out to awk to do the filtering on the fly:

```
import subprocess
import pandas as pd

cmd = "awk '(NR - 1) % 6 > 1' test.csv"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
df = pd.read_csv(proc.stdout, header=None)
```

The awk command will skip the first two lines out of every group of 6. Since the filtering is done on a streaming basis, this is very memory efficient, and since the filtering is done in a separate process, it'll be fast as well.