# Python and Pandas - Removing footer in multiple files with the same break

Tags: python, excel, pandas, footer

I am doing data analysis on a group of different excel files, each with a footer. The start point of the footer changes based on the total number of rows. The footer starts in the first column as a blank cell then has text that is not formatted like the rest of the data in the column. I am trying to come up with a footer length variable to drop into skip_footer when I read the files.

```
  df looks like    
  +--------------------+
  |   A     B      C   |
  +--------------------+
  | Data  Data   Data  |
  | Data  Data   Data  |
  | [Blank]            |
  | This is            |
  | The footer         |
  | I need to remove   |
  +--------------------+
```

I have tried using both methods at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138175/pandas-ignore-all-lines-following-a-specific-string-when-reading-a-file-into-a), but I can't seem to get either to work. One of the errors I am getting is invalid file. Im 99% sure that the invalid file is coming because the file is an xlsx. I don't get an error when I open and read the file, only when I try to run functions on it.

```
 Code: 
 import os
 direct = "path"
 file = open(direct, "file name"), "r")

 import itertools as it
 def get_footer(file_):
      with open(file_) as f:
         g = it.dropwhile(lambda x: x != ' ', f)
         footer_len = len([i for i, _ in enumerate(g)])
     return footer_len

 footer_len = get_footer(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to figure out how to do the above, but I have a much easier answer.

```
 import pandas as pd
 File = pd.read_excel()
 NoFooter = File[:-6]
```

Comment: @DataNoob, you could also use the `skip_footer` parameter within pandas.read_excel().  See doc here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html